# How to get class reference by String name?

Tags: java, reflection, compiler-errors, quartz-scheduler

I am attempting to make the following method call dynamic:

```
JobDetail job = newJob(RunMeJob.class)
                  .withIdentity("myJob", "group1")
                  .build();
```

By doing the following:

```
private void scheduleJob(final SchedulerJob job, final SchedulerTrigger trigger) {

    final String fullyQualifiedName = "com.crm.scheduler.job.RunMeJob";//"com.crm.scheduler.job" + job.getImplementation();

    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(fullyQualifiedName, false, null);

    JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(cls)
              .withIdentity(job.getExternalReference(), trigger.getExternalReference())
              .build();
}
```

But I am receiving the following error:

> The method newJob(Class< ? extends Job>) in the type JobBuilder is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Class< capture#3-of ?>)

Here is the `RunMeJob` class:

```
package com.crm.scheduler.job;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.crm.scheduler.task.RunMeTask;

@Component
public class RunMeJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        new RunMeTask().printMe();
    }
}
```

How can I dynamically specify the class?

Comment: Can you share the signature of `newJob` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, basically, but you can't pass any old `Class` object to the `newJob` method - it must be a `Class` instance that represent a `Job`, and has to be specified as such in its generics:

```
Class<? extends Job> cls = 
    (Class<Job>) Class.forName(fullyQualifiedName, false, null);
```